# WcfTestClient, "The client was unable to retrieve service metadata ..."

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I get this error when I attempt to run the wcftestclient application: "The client was unable to retrieve service metadata..."

What is odd that this happens when I load the program; before the UI to choose which service to connect to is loaded.  I presume it's "helpfully" remembering the last service to which I connected, unfortunately this is no longer running and I have no idea what it could be (since the wcftestclient exits when this error pops up).

Does any one know where it may be storing this information and how I would go about deleting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you launch the application from the command line, passing in the URI of the service you want to test it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check this folder on your machine:

C:\Documents and Settings*User*\Local Settings\Application Data\Temp\Test Client Projects

All your clients are saved there.